# App works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have this code in my "show.html.erb"

```
<div><blockquote class="pull-left">
          <p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.content %> </p>
          <small><%= @l.author %> </small>
          <button class="btn btn-mini", "pull=right" type="button">Następny -></button>
        </blockquote></div>
      </div>
```

and in my "kalendar_controller.rb" I have:

```
  def show

   @l = Joke.find_by(id: rand(1..Joke.count)) 
   @t = Time.now.strftime("%A")
   @week = Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0 ? "#{trans} " "PARZYSTE" : "NIEPARZYSTE"
  end
```

I have run these codes on heroku:

```
$ git push
$ git push heroku
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Everything works locally so I expect it to work on Heroku. But then I get greeted with

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

At this point I'm not really sure what's going on. I check the heroku logs and found this `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method`content' for nil:NilClass):`maybe this could be the problem (not sure yet though). But I have`@l`defined which picks a random joke from the database so why is the log mentioning`nil:NilClass` at all. Any help with fixing this please?

EDIT:

my heroku log:

```
2013-12-12T13:38:13.734760+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered kalendar/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2013-12-12T13:38:13.735007+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
2013-12-12T13:38:13.735007+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:   
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        <div><blockquote class="pull-left">
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:          <small><%= @l.author %> </small>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:          <p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.content %> </p>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:          <button class="btn btn-mini", "pull=right" type="button">Następny -></button>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        </blockquote></div>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737468+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/kalendar/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_kalendar_show_html_erb___3142504778803122676_70084739238140'
2013-12-12T13:38:13.737825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:   
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:          <p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.content %> </p>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        <div><blockquote class="pull-left">
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:          <small><%= @l.author %> </small>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:          <button class="btn btn-mini", "pull=right" type="button">Następny -></button>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        </blockquote></div>
2013-12-12T13:38:13.739896+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/kalendar/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_kalendar_show_html_erb___3142504778803122676_70084739238140'
2013-12-12T13:38:13.740233+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.740233+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:38:13.741057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:42:13.686261+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by KalendarController#show as HTML
2013-12-12T13:42:13.685334+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 90.156.104.195 at 2013-12-12 13:42:13 +0000
2013-12-12T13:42:13.685334+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 90.156.104.195 at 2013-12-12 13:42:13 +0000
2013-12-12T13:42:13.686261+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by KalendarController#show as HTML
2013-12-12T13:42:13.700988+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
2013-12-12T13:42:13.700988+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered kalendar/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2013-12-12T13:42:13.700988+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered kalendar/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:   
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:          <small><%= @l.author %> </small>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        <div><blockquote class="pull-left">
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:          <p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.content %> </p>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:          <button class="btn btn-mini", "pull=right" type="button">Następny -></button>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        </blockquote></div>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:   
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:          <small><%= @l.author %> </small>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:          <p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.content %> </p>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/kalendar/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_kalendar_show_html_erb___3142504778803122676_70084739238140'
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        <div><blockquote class="pull-left">
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:          <button class="btn btn-mini", "pull=right" type="button">Następny -></button>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703331+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/kalendar/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_kalendar_show_html_erb___3142504778803122676_70084739238140'
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        </blockquote></div>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.700988+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
2013-12-12T13:42:13.709613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=31ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:05.673627+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:44:13.629310+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:44:36.274158+00:00 heroku[run.2266]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:44:46.099637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2013-12-12T13:44:48.421969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-12-12T13:44:53.194153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:44:54.886028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=748ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:58.494336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=52ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:59.893294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=44ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:45:01.715005+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=113ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:23.059938+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:45:22.966815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:27.944462+00:00 heroku[run.2266]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:44:42.439607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-12-12T13:49:22.429144+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:49:25.743801+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T13:49:25.786121+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-12-12T13:49:25.875234+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:49:29.211204+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-12T13:49:29.238443+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:49:34.966709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:51:03.227983+00:00 heroku[run.9695]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:51:08.517393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:51:09.560231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1266
```

I also did run `heroku run rake db:populate` and that wouldn't even work.

Latest Logs:

```
Last login: Thu Dec 12 19:18:11 on ttys003
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/siaW/Desktop/kalendar/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

emmanuels-imac:kalendar siaW$ heroku logs
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:        </blockquote></div>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.703608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.700988+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-12-12T13:42:13.702991+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass):
2013-12-12T13:42:13.709613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=31ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:05.673627+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:44:13.629310+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:44:36.274158+00:00 heroku[run.2266]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:44:46.099637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-12-12 13:44:46] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943708+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-12-12T13:44:46.943517+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2013-12-12T13:44:48.421969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-12-12T13:44:53.194153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:44:54.886028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=748ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:58.494336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=52ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:59.893294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=44ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:45:01.715005+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=113ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:23.059938+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:45:22.966815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:44:27.944462+00:00 heroku[run.2266]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:44:42.439607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-12-12T13:49:22.429144+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T13:49:25.743801+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T13:49:25.786121+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-12-12T13:49:25.875234+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T13:49:29.211204+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-12T13:49:29.238443+00:00 heroku[run.4519]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:49:34.966709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:51:03.227983+00:00 heroku[run.9695]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T13:51:08.517393+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:51:09.560231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T13:52:05.530539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:01:12.840421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:01:13.798926+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:02:25.893053+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:10:40.052935+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=100ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:17:42.867494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:19:04.381488+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:19:09.039027+00:00 heroku[run.2181]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:19:09.145701+00:00 heroku[run.2181]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:19:09.288308+00:00 heroku[run.2181]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate`
2013-12-12T14:19:12.831097+00:00 heroku[run.2181]: Process exited with status 1
2013-12-12T14:19:12.860881+00:00 heroku[run.2181]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:23:08.011600+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:23:13.078679+00:00 heroku[run.4911]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:23:13.533233+00:00 heroku[run.4911]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:23:13.581313+00:00 heroku[run.4911]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate`
2013-12-12T14:23:19.847369+00:00 heroku[run.4911]: Process exited with status 1
2013-12-12T14:23:19.860400+00:00 heroku[run.4911]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:26:31.825431+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:26:36.581342+00:00 heroku[run.4120]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:26:36.626793+00:00 heroku[run.4120]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-12-12T14:26:41.855736+00:00 heroku[run.4120]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:26:41.839844+00:00 heroku[run.4120]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-12T14:26:50.477466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=37ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:29:14.123333+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:29:18.312942+00:00 heroku[run.3578]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:29:18.371912+00:00 heroku[run.3578]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-12-12T14:29:18.471482+00:00 heroku[run.3578]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:29:23.362281+00:00 heroku[run.3578]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-12T14:31:05.504490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=46ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:29:23.379276+00:00 heroku[run.3578]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:35:18.938824+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:35:22.937717+00:00 heroku[run.9410]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:35:26.995322+00:00 heroku[run.9410]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:35:30.893618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=34ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:35:22.744507+00:00 heroku[run.9410]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:35:22.803390+00:00 heroku[run.9410]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-12-12T14:35:26.979877+00:00 heroku[run.9410]: Process exited with status 0
2013-12-12T14:38:53.954686+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=258ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:41:40.175479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=89ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:49:29.480931+00:00 heroku[run.2515]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:50:54.030490+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by siawmensah@gmail.com
2013-12-12T14:50:58.893089+00:00 heroku[run.7658]: State changed from starting to up
2013-12-12T14:50:58.975265+00:00 heroku[run.7658]: Awaiting client
2013-12-12T14:50:59.005656+00:00 heroku[run.7658]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2013-12-12T14:51:00.699641+00:00 heroku[run.7658]: Process exited with status 128
2013-12-12T14:51:01.199142+00:00 heroku[run.7658]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:50:00.792442+00:00 heroku[run.2515]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:52:27.379216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=255ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:53:12.077208+00:00 heroku[run.3491]: State changed from up to complete
2013-12-12T14:54:17.017016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=33ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T14:54:44.964666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=hidden-river-2301.herokuapp.com fwd="90.156.104.195" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=1266
2013-12-12T15:57:38.455980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-12-12T15:57:38.456870+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
emmanuels-imac:kalendar siaW$
```

Comment: Can you get a bit more from the Heroku logs.  You've not given much to go on

Comment: you database on `heroku` empty and this not work `Joke.find_by(id: rand(1..Joke.count))`

Comment: i posted my log. and did `heroku run rake db:populate` in an effort to fill the db. but that didn't work either.

Comment: @l is nil, which is why you're getting the error message.  So for some reason this is failing:  @l = Joke.find_by(id: rand(1..Joke.count)).  Why not try Joke.all.count to see if there are any in the table?  Monk_Code suggested that your database tables aren't being populated for some reason.  I think he's correct

Comment: i think it's failing because i haven't populated the db on heroku. but i run `heroku run rake db:populate` which doesn't work anyway. Or maybe i should put some data in `seed.rb`? BEFORE running the `db:populate`?

Comment: to answer the above, yes, you need to have data in your seeds.rb file in order to populate the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your random method sometimes return an id value which is not present in the database, therefor the find_by method return nil instead of raising an error, which is good.

However instead of using Donovan's method to show a message when not present, I suggest that you randomly select an ID value from an existing array of present id's.

example:

```
random_id = Joke.all.map(&:id).sample
@joke = Joke.find_by_id(random_id)
```

Now al you need to do is make sure that the database is populated, since [].sample still returns nil.

EDIT:
Also I suggest using logic when handling variable names, when returning a single Joke object use @joke and when returning an array of jokes use @jokes, this will make it more easy to understand.

Comment: I like this too, I suggest a combination of both answers, since you could still end up with nil using this solution.

Comment: That is indeed a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple check to be sure @l is valid before attempting to display it, something like this:

```
<p id="mycontainer"><%= @l.nil? ? 'No jokes found, sorry' : @l.content %> </p>
```

Comment: same state. not change.

Comment: wait, you're still getting "undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass"?  Did you push your changes to Heroku?

Comment: yes i did push to Heroku just now after the changes and still nothing change. same error. still getting `undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I can only surmise you're using `@l.content` elsewhere on the page as well, you'll want to make the same changes anywhere you're using `@l`.  However, make sure you also see the solution by @dennis

Comment: well for me this is strange. cause i'm using `@l.content` just once. on one page. I tried @dennis' solution. same thing. where from this `nil:NilClass` thing? i put some jokes in the database locally and pushed everything to heroku :(

Comment: heroku doesn't use your local database, you'll need to populate the database used by heroku.

Comment: please post the latest heroku logs, with the changes suggested by @dennis and I.

Comment: I'm not seeing the content error in your latest logs... they are in reverse chronological order, meaning the newest entries are at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

rand() will not work on heroku

try:

```
@l = Joke.all.sample
```

Comment: Rand() will not work on a Postgres database, so this is not Heroku related.